# Trying to use in place repair upgrade on laptop that won't boot to start screen

Tags: windows-10, boot

I'm trying to get the in-place repair upgrade to work for my laptop that won't boot to the sign in screen, won't go into safe mode, won't run `sfc` and it also won't load my system restore point

`chkdsk /scan /perf` ran but returned error `A snaphot error occurred while scanning this drive.` but it will go into recovery mode and have me to log into my profile to run the command prompt.

I want to try to run an ISO I created with the media creation tool to repair windows but I can only access the recovery mode on the hobbled pc.

Can the ISO be run from the command prompt in recovery mode?

A youtuber called ThioJoe stated that the in-place repair option must be run from within windows to work (8min58secs in linked video).

I am trying to reset my pc while keeping personal files and apps. The reset option I'm seeing in recovery wants to in the best case remove my personal apps but keep my files.

Most relevant info to my case starts at 6:55 mark:
https://youtu.be/yidWdy-Xwdk?t=416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trying to get the in-place repair upgrade to work for my laptop that
> won't boot to the sign in screen, won't go into safe mode, won't run
> sfc and it also won't load my system restore point and chkdsk /scan
> /perf ran but returned error

You cannot run Repair Install if Windows is not running. Not possible.

The only thing you can do here is try to recover your data (USB Boot if SSD drive, remove HDD and put in carrier), and then see if you can do a fresh install of Windows.

If fresh install fails, replace the drive and then install Windows and recover your data.

Comment: Ok I see. It looks like I'll probably be able to keep my data but will have to probably reinstall my apps and also windows itself.

Comment: Based on my current research and your reply I will tentatively accept this as the answer to the question. If anyone else has some tips and info feel free to share.

Answer (score 2):

If running the Windows installation from the boot media succeeds in
detecting your existing Windows installation,
then the effect will be exactly the same as the Repair Installation.

Only if the existing installation is not detected, then the installation
will be done from scratch with a fresh Windows installation
that requires installing all your applications.